# mod_dosdetectorで画像を除外する際、動的な画像はDoS攻撃検知の対象にしたい

Tags: apache

apacheのモジュールmod_dosdetectorでdos対策をしたいと思っています。

適用する環境はjavaサーブレットが動いているwebサーバです。

制限対象にするアクセスはサーバへの全てのアクセスではなく、 
サーブレットのアクションに対してのアクセスが主で、 
同じサーバ内の画像ディレクトリに保存されている画像ファイルへのアクセスはDos攻撃とみなさずに制限対象外にする想定です。

そこでmod_dosdetectorのDoSIgnoreContentTypeの設定項目で、 
実現しようと思うのですが、 
コンテンツタイプを指定すると画像は問題なく制限の対象外になるのですが、 
サーブレットのアクションにアクセスした際に 
そのアクションが返すjspが同じサーバの画像をクライアントに返していると、 
そのアクセス自体が制限の対象外になってしまいます。

このような場合、対処法等はあるのでしょうか。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

ソースコードをざっと見たところ `DoSDetection` ディレクティブの[コンテキスト](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/directive-dict.html#Context) は「ディレクトリ」でもいいようなので、静的な画像のあるディレクトリあるいは URL で `DoSDetection Off` すればいいと思います。(未確認)

```
<Directory /path/to/static/image/dir>
    DoSDetection Off
</Directory>
```